# Object Destructuring Assignment Behaving Weirdly in Constructor

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, electron, destructuring

I'm using electron and React and I have some code that looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const { arr } = this.props;
  ipcRenderer.on('event', () => {
    console.log(this.props.arr); // will log updated values
    console.log(arr); // always logs initial value 
  });
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? I can't reproduce this anywhere else. I've tried doing similar things with window event handlers and closures to see if they behave in the same way, but they don't. Am I missing something really obvious?

```
const obj = { arr: [1, 2, 3] };
const { arr } = obj;
obj.arr.push(4);
arr.push(5);

console.log(obj.arr); // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(arr); // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something really obvious?

Presumably a *new* array is assigned to `this.props.arr`. Simple repro:

```js
const obj = { arr: [1, 2, 3] };
const { arr } = obj;
obj.arr = [1];

console.log(obj.arr); // => [1]
console.log(arr); // => [1, 2, 3]
```

Destructuring is nothing magical. These two are equivalent:

```
const { arr } = this.props;
const arr = this.props.arr;
```

`arr` holds the value that `this.props.arr` had at the time of the *assignment*, whereas `this.props.arr` gives you the value at the time you *access* it.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.